# How to share Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have created a maven archetype to generate the project structure, now I want to share the archetype within team but I cannot publish the archetype to any repository. 
Is there a way by which I can share the archetype as a jar file or a zip file or anything else. So that the other developers can use it by putting it in their local maven repositories and generate the project structures ?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly cannot push even the archetype project source to an internal repository, then you can still share either the archetype project or the generated .jar.

## Project

Simply .zip the archetype project and share it with your team. Each team member can then run:

```
mvn clean install
```

This will install the archetype into their local .m2 and create/update their local archetype catalog  (`~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`) with the new archetype entry. From Eclipse, you can then go to:

```
Preferences > Maven > Archetypes > Add Local Catalog...
```

and select the `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` file.

## JAR

Each person on your team can take the .jar and place it in their local .m2 repo in the correct place based on `groupId` and `artifactId` of the archetype .jar. They will then need to manually update/create their local archetype catalog (mentioned above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-catalog xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <archetypes>
    <archetype>
      <groupId><!-- Fill in --></groupId>
      <artifactId><!-- Fill in --></artifactId>
      <version><!-- Fill in --></version>
      <description><!-- Fill in --></description>
    </archetype>
  </archetypes>
</archetype-catalog>
```

From this point the process is the same as above (Add the local archetype catalog to Eclipse).

---

IMO distributing a .zip of the archetype project requires the least amount of manual effort if you really can't upload it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt...

I guess you already have been able to generate your archetype.jar file. So, my suggestion is:

1. Share archetype.jar file
2. Execute in that folder the following command:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar-archetype-file> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
   ```

After executing the command, the jar is installed in your local repo. You can generate the project with for instance IntelliJ or go to the path where you want to generate the project and...

```
mvn archetype:generate
```